# FInd who deleted permission set in salesforce

Tags: permissions, salesforce, audit, audit-trail

I want to know the audit trail with regards to one user in Salesforce.
The user got his permission sets deleted by some process/user and want to find out who did it.

Is this possible?
I dont think permission set is set in the fields for audit trail.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, download the setup audit trail CSV and you can search that to find out who made the change:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&language=en_US&type=0